# Email not getting redirected to as per MX record to business email server

Tags: postfix

I've purchased business email so all emails to `contact@anikadigital.in` should go to `privateemail.com` as per the MX record of `anikadigital.in`.

Here is the MX lookup of anikadigital.in:

```
DNS server handling your query: localhost
 DNS server's address:  127.0.0.1#53

 Non-authoritative answer:
 anikadigital.in    mail exchanger = 10 mx1.privateemail.com.
 anikadigital.in    mail exchanger = 10 mx2.privateemail.com.
```

but still I'm getting this error in the `syslog` file:

```
 A091021432: to=<contact@anikadigital.in>, relay=none, delay=0.02, delays=0.01/0/0/0.01, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (User unknown in virtual alias table)
```

How can that be?

Here is the postfix configuration. I've mangled other domains however I've retained the anikadigital.in domain  as it is:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
always_bcc = contact@anikadigital.in
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost, localhost.localdomain, localhost
myhostname = host.digittions.in
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_domains = digittions.in indiacc.com cffd.com def.com duplicateticket.com karera.digitaltransactions.in mail.digittions.in idoff.com accrec.in anikadigital.in passport.anikadigital.in pan.anikadigital.in tpst.in
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Comment: The email is to `contact@`. In your virtual file you only have `contactus@`.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider how does it matter? because the MX record is pointing to privateemail.com server so any email sent to contact@anikadigita.in should go to my new business email mail box and to this server on which site is hosted

Comment: So, your actual question is `Why does email reach my server X even when the MX record points to server Y`?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider actually yes

Comment: I took the liberty of removing everything irrelevant to the actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specifically configured Postfix to handle mail for anikadigital.in, in `virtual_alias_domains`. When you put a domain here, Postfix always delivers the mail locally.

If the mail is not meant to be delivered locally, the domain must not appear in `virtual_alias_domains`, `virtual_alias_maps`, `myhostname` or `mydestination`.

Comment: Ok i want contact@anikadigital.in to be delivered to privateemail.com server. But I want to locally receive any emails to pan.anikadigital.in and passport.anikadigital.in .

Comment: Those are different names, though. Pick the ones you want and remove the rest.

Comment: And you need to set mx records for those domains if you expect emails to them from outside

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple possible reasons for this:

- outdated DNS results on the sender side
- a sender that doesn't adhere to the SMTP standards
- spam bots
- ...

If you have a service that is reachable from the internet, there will be people or bots trying to abuse it.

Your server rejects the mails, that is good, but there is not much you can do about this.  Basically, just ignore it.

Comment: the what is the solution?

Comment: One good spot for verifying correct DNS/MX/Mailserver behaviours after a re-config is to use the free tools at https://mxtoolbox.com/

Comment: @IngvarJ I've edited the question